# jQuery Multiple Click Events Attached to Body Element (AJAX-loaded content)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using PHP to access the Twitter API and AJAX requests to perform operations without needing to refresh the page.

In my current setup, when the page first loads, it is blank. Using jQuery, on `document.ready()`, I perform an AJAX request that directs to a PHP page that grabs a timeline, builds the HTML structure in a string, and returns it to the AJAX success function. I then append that to a div which renders as HTML.

The problem I'm having is, because I have so much dynamically-generated content, my click events in jQuery are overriding each other. I have several `.on("click")` events that are attached to the `body` element (because they don't exist on `document.ready()`).

```
$('body').unbind('click').on('click', '.element', function(e){...}
```

The result of this is that the event listener that is farthest down in the code works, but not the others that are above it. How can I solve this issue? My first thought was `e.stopPropogation` or `e.stopImmediatePropogation`, as I think I've used those before in a similar situation, but I'm not quite sure.

Thank you in advance for advice!

Comment: why you don't put your `$('body').unbind('click').on('click', '.element', function(e){...}` on the root element, so that it not rebind after dynamic content load?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; are you really wondering why previous click handlers don’t execute any more, when you are removing _all_ of them before adding a single new one …?

Comment: @shayanypn Wouldn't binding it to `$('html')` still have the same issues as `$('body')`?

Comment: @CBroe How am I removing all of them? Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the events to the elements in the success() function of ajax after the request to the server has been completed.

**AJAX**

```
        $.ajax({
            url : 'process.php',
            data: { ... },
            success : function(data) {
                document.getElementById("my-element").innerHTML = data;
                $('#loaded-element').bind('click', function(){
                    ...
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: This solved the problem for click event bound at the top of the code, but now the one at the bottom (which was the one that previously worked), is now not functioning. :(

Comment: **EDIT:** I realized that I could now bind my click events to the actual selectors, since they were being added after the elements were added to the page. So now they BOTH work. Thank you!